# Difference between ip link add ... vlan and bridge vlan add vid...?

Tags: linux, ip, vlan

I am getting into details of VLANs on Linux and I came across those 2 commands:

```
[root@machine ~]# bridge vlan add vid 100 dev em1
[root@machine ~]# ip link add link em1 name em1.100 type vlan id 100
```

The first one will add a VLAN to em1:

```
[root@machine ~]# bridge vlan show
port    vlan ids
em1      1 PVID Egress Untagged
         100
```

while the second one will create a new interface:

```
[root@machine ~]# ip a s dev em1.100
27: em1.100@em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:ca:3a:70:8f:d0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

What are the differences between those 2?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see from `man bridge`, `bridge vlan ...` manipulates the **VLAN filter list** of a bridge (that describes which ports are enabled for which VLAN tags), while `ip link add ... type vlan` will **create a new network interface** that you can use to access VLAN tagged packets from applications, by giving it an IP address etc.

Both are totally different things and have nothing in common (except that both deal with VLAN tags, but in a completely different way).

Comment: `bridge vlan ... manipulates the VLAN filter list of a bridge` - but `em1` is not a bridge, it's a physical interface, why is it allowed then to manipulate it via `bridge vlan ...`?

Comment: `em1` is a physical interface that is used as the port of a bridge. The bridge controls the ports: It forwards packets between them, and can add or remove VLAN tags for certain ports. So you are not "manipulating a physical interface via `bridge vlan`", you are telling the bridge how to treat a physical interface that is part of a bridge w.r.t. VLAN handling.

Answer (score 0):

**The first one**  enables the vlan to be passed through the interface otherwise the vlan gets pruned, a bridge must be then configured with:

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge    
ip link set dev br0 type bridge vlan_filtering 1
ip link set em1 master br0
```

In your example the interface em1 has as native the vlan 1 and member the vlan 100 with no interface, all other vlans get pruned

**The second one**  creates a new (sub)interface which consequently gets untagged traffic (VLAN 100 won't get passed to any bridge the em1 is assigned to) In your example em1.100 is a new interface and to  bridge it you need a new (sub)bridge created like this

```
ip link add name br0.100 type bridge
ip link set dev br0.100 up
ip link set em1.100 master br0.100
```